# Flutter bloc with calling api on an interval

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an app that accesses two api's that contain location data that updates regularly (every 5 seconds or so). I want to utilize flutter and `flutter_bloc` to manage my state, but I'm not sure where the interval would come into play. I understand bloc and how the ui interacts with it with `BlocBuilder` and `BlocProvider`, as well as providing a repository that handles the api calls. What I'm not sure about is where to put the interval/timer. My idea was to do a normal bloc setup:

```
class DataBloc extends Bloc<DataEvent, DataState> {
    //constructor

     @override
     Stream<DataState> mapEventToState(DataEvent event) async* {
         if (event is FetchData) {
              var data = repository.getData();
              yield* _mapFetchDataToState(data);
         }
     }
}
```

In the ui:

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dataBloc = BlocProvider.of<DataBloc>(context);

    Timer.periodic(fiveSeconds, (Timer t) => dataBloc.add(FetchData()));
    
    return ui stuff
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right way to leverage BLoCs and/or timers. But I basically need to call the api on an interval and then have the data update in my ui without a full refresh of all the widgets. They're going to be icons on a google map, and I want the icons to update their locations when the data I pull is updated. How can I accomplish this? For reference, I've looked at the flutter_bloc docs for the timer app [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertimertutorial) and I thought it was a little overkill and that my idea above was simpler, just not sure if this is the right way. I'm pretty new to flutter so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomend not to put initializing code inside `build`. Make it a `StatefulWidget` and add a `dispose` method to clear the timer. And inside `initState` setup the timer.

There's no right way in programming. There are best practices, so as long as it work for your use case is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would either put the timer into the bloc/cubit because its part of your logic and not of your ui.

Or if you use a repository I would probably use a stream listen to it in your bloc and periodically update the stream in your repo.

But any better suggestions are more than welcome, because I am also looking for some kind of 'the way to do'...